# Require scoped module in Clojurescript

Tags: react-native, clojurescript, re-natal

I have started using the `:target :nodejs` compiler options for a `cljs` project ([src](http://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2017-07-17-cleaner-clojurescript-react-native-interop.html)). By and large, it works well.

However, when attempting to convert `@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl` to the updated `require` syntax, e.g.

```
(:require [@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl])
```

it fails -

`Library name must be specified as a symbol`

as the npm module is scoped with `@`. Using a string does not work either.

This works-

```
(set! js/MapboxGL (js/require "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl"))
```

But I was curious if there was any way to get this compiled with the `require` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using `1.9.854` or above,

you can now use string in :require

```
(:require ["@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl" :as mapbox])
```

hope you enjoy using ClojureScript

Comment: Thanks for the note. I will give this a shot when I return to the project next week and report back.

Comment: It turns out that the Mapbox lib returns an object that must be accessed from `:default`,  e.g. `(def _map (.-default mapbox))`, which is why it failed when I tried a string originally. Thanks for the note. Your answer works great.

Comment: really recommend everyone to join clojure's slack channels. you can get more fast and good answer